# Meteor: Join by userId but display username, publishing user data?

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-helper

So, I have bunch of collections joined with Meteor.users collection by userId as foreign key. E.g. I have Posts collection and each post has its own page. On a post page I have userId as author and a bunch of comments(from Comments collection) on that post each has postId and userId. UserIds are ugly, instead I would like to display **usernames**. How would you achieve that? Any smart package that I can use or working example? I don't like the idea of publishing all users data. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to publish all data. In publish method you can use `fields` specifier in that way:

`Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {'username': 1}});`

That way you have only `_id` and `username` published.

Then in meteor helper you can have:

```
username: function() {
  var user = Meteor.user.findOne(this.userId);
  return user.username || user.profile.name;
}
```

if Post is your context

Comment: Yes. After I posted this question, I used publish-composite package. Now using this method I only publish username and profile fields. But another problem is arisen xD. I also use useraccounts package and third party account services. Facebook and Google provides user data like this: **profile.name: "John"**  unlike ATCreateUserServer method creates user object with **username: "John"**. Now on the client I need to figure out how helper function to can return username(or name) depending on accounts services. I am not the most experienced programmer, so fingers crossed. thanks

Comment: I edited my answer - you can use logical operator || - the helper tries to return `username` but if it is empty or undefined it tries to return `profile.name`. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I have user.profile.name for all services. On Accounts.onCreateUser function user.profile = {}; user.profile.name = options.username; return user; Now no need to use logic on the helper. Thank you, appreciate a lot.